# The type org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, android, annotations, xmlpullparser

Hi I am getting a compilation error:

> The type org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Can any one help me to fix this?

Comment: That interface definitely exists in Android. Make sure that you are building an Android project and that you have a valid build target specified.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for comment . I have bit modified the order of jars in java build path. will that be the reason for this

Comment: Possibly. I usually leave the build path order alone, since you cannot control the classpath order at runtime.

Comment: @CommonsWare : okay, will rearrange and try.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a jar file，like this: xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, below is download link:

> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlpull1131jar.htm.

Hope this answer can help you.